# Can you start the Explorer copy dialog from the command line?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-transfer

Is it possible to trigger an Explorer style file copy in Windows, such that the copy file dialog is displayed?

I'm aware of `copy`, `xcopy` and `robocopy` commands but I'm specifically looking to spawn the copy dialog.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way from command line to show the Explorer copy dialog / file dialog.

You can use a small VBScript snippet instead:

```
Dim objShell :  Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.FindFiles
```

Comment: Are you saying there is a method of the Shell.Application object to copy files? What is it?

Comment: Ah, you can use `Shell.NameSpace` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-namespace to get a `Folder` object for the destination folder and then e.g. `.CopyHere` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-copyhere with the source folder name, and it will copy it with Windows Explorer.